# Keep CakePHP 3 app skeleton up to date

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp 3 project i created using composer. Keeping all the dependencies up to date is easy with composer but what about the app skeleton itself since it's the base of the app and not upgradable with composer? How can incorporate updates to the app skeleton into my app, other than manually tracking changes and applying patches?

Thanks in advance